# Analyzing chi-square test for categorical features

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

I have a dataset with many categorical features and want to find the correlation between those features. Currently, I am using the chi-square test of independence tests for that.

According to the test, if p-value < significance level (generally 0.05), I can reject my null hypothesis and say variables are related. First, we create an observed contingency table. **My doubt is if I'm having many cells with value 0 (i.e. sparse matrix) in the contingency table, can I rely on chi_square statistics** because chi_square assumptions are:

1. The two samples are independent
2. No expected cell count is = 0
3. No more than 20% of the cells have an expected cell count < 5

Just to be more clear, let me explain my doubt with the help of an example. Let's say I have features called 'city' and 'state' in the US dataset. If Atlanta city is in Georgia State, all the cells between Atlanta and other states will be 0 in the contingency table of city and state, and thus assumptions won't satisfy. Can I still use the chi-square test here? If yes, please explain the reason and if no, please explain what to do in such cases.

I took reference from [this](https://www.pythonfordatascience.org/chi-square-test-of-independence-python/) source.

If I am missing something important here, please help me know that. Thanks in advance.